# zsh: Do I need to close file descriptors?

Tags: zsh, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I use the following code to both output something to stdout, and pipe it to a program:

```
function example() {
    local fd1
    {
        exec {fd1}>&1
        { echo hi >&$fd1 } | true
    } always { exec {fd1}>&- }
}
```

I am wondering if I can safely drop `always { exec {fd1}>&- }`. `fd1` goes out of scope after the function finishes anyways.

Comment: This is a subjective question, not likely to get a definitive answer. The short answer is, you don't have to, but it is a "good" practice to do so

Comment: @Inian In what conditions can it have any bad consequences at all?

Comment: @Inian This isn't any more subjective than "do I need to free memory after I malloc it, even if the last pointer to it goes out of scope?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep `always { exec {fd1}>&- }`. If you get rid of that, the variable containing the file descriptor will go out of scope, but the file descriptor won't be closed, resulting in leaking it. You can see this by doing `ls -l /proc/$$/fd` before and after running your function without that line. Each run of the function will permanently add another FD to that list. Eventually, you'll run out of file descriptors and won't be able to open any new ones, which will break things.